# how to customize the Facebook Login Button with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to customize the Facebook button for my ReactJs website, but it seems to be not working. I want my Facebook button look like the following design:

[image]

Google login is working as I expected, but facebook is kept appearing like following:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-fast-mowfd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your https://codesandbox.io/ demo would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question, I just stupidly did not see the correct way of importing the FacebookLogin

`import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props'`

This is how the import should be done. After that I was able to make my own custom style through render prop:

````
  appId="1088597931155576"
  autoLoad
  callback={responseFacebook}
  render={renderProps => (
    <button onClick={renderProps.onClick}>This is my custom FB button</button>
  )}
/>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing very easily. What you have to do is you have to design your custom button and then use the `onclick` property.

Here how you do it:
Include this thing where you want to show the Facebook login button and don't forget to style this button according to your needs.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<button onclick="fb_login();">Login using facebook</button>
```

Now here is the code you have to include in your page that has the `fb_login` function defined. You have to put your app id to see the results.

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'your_app_id_here',
        oauth: true,
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true // parse XFBML
    });

};

function fb_login() {
    FB.login(function (response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
                // you can store this data into your database             
            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'public_profile,email'
    });
}
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}()
```